# Good website screenshot plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation

I'm looking for a good plugin I can integrate in my template to show screenshots. Today I am using Wordpress Simple Website Screenshot, but it's too unstable. I post a lot of posts per day and my problem is that it doesn't load all the screenshots. You have to reload several times before it shows. This is not acceptable for me.

One solution could be to store the screenshots locally to make it more stable. Do you have any suggestions how to make this as stable as possible?

Link to example post: http://bit.ly/jjO4z1 (with bit.ly because of google searches on the site)

Comment: This code is awesome. Just put it in your functions.php file then use the short code! http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-generate-website-screenshots-for-your-wordpress-site/ (I think what he's looking for M. Taylor would be something which cache's a screen shot of the link, doesn't have to have every possible webpage...)

Answer (score 2):

I would try this plugin, it uses the WordPress.com system: [An Automated Way to Take Screenshots of any Website](http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/2010/02/automated-take-screenshots-website-free/)

Comment: BM Shots was exactly what I was going to recommend!

Comment: LOL. BM Shots. Snicker.

Comment: Wordpress Simple Website Screenshot is also using the mshots. The problem is that the screenshots is not cached before I enter the post. I need the screenshots to always be visible for the users. Today only 3/4 of the screenshots are available.

Comment: So you want a screenshot tool that already has a cache of every possible webpage? Your only semi-realistic option then seems to be a Google API.